# Textarea issue with IE6 - I'm using Jquery framework for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, internet-explorer-6

All other browsers are working well except for IE6. I have textareas in a JS form that aren't viewing correctly in IE6. I'm using Jquery framework for javascript. I wish to have a horizontal line at the bottom of each textarea to make it look like the user is completing the sentence. In IE6 this line isn't visible until the user starts typing in the textarea.

Form is located at:
http://handlemycomplaint.com.au/pdfletter/Model/User/form/form.php

Does anyone have a suggestion for a fix?

Comment: IE 6 is only <5% of the market share.  Is it a requirement for you web site?  If not.  Don't bother with it.

Comment: Hi John, Unfortunately it is a requirement to have it compatable with IE6. Issues only involve CSS so I hope to resolve them without too many dramas.

Answer (score 0):

In jon.css try:

```
 #testform textarea{ background:#FFF  url(../images/textarea.gif) repeat-x left bottom;padding-top:3px;margin-left:5px;border:none;}
```

You can use background images on textareas properly in IE6, though it can be pretty tricky to setup.  If this doesn't work I would just trying to debug by changing the css settings until you get something to show up and go from there.

Btw, if you run into a scrolling problem check here for help: http://www.readactor.com/tutorials/fix-ie7-scrolling-background-problem-in-textarea-form-fields/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try it out and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

This idea is a hack, but fortunately hacks are pretty rare with IE6, so I'm sure it'll be the only time you'll ever have to do one.

Why not just declare the initial value of each textarea as a single space character?  For example:

```
<textarea style="overflow: auto; font-family: Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 13px;" tabindex="15" id="wishlist1" cols="89" rows="1" name="wishlist1"> </textarea>
```

Notice the whitespace between the textarea tags.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions. I'll give it a go and let you know how I go with it!